# Structure XML response data to Array

Tags: ios, uitableview, xml-parsing

The xml response is something like this

```
<detail>
<Category A>
<details></details>
</Category A>
</detail>
<detail>
<Category B>
<details></details>
</Category B>
</detail>
<detail>
<Category A>
<details></details>
</Category A>
</detail>
```

I want to put them in a structured array but i really don't have a clue how...
I would like to have it like this

```
<Category A>    
<detail>
<details></details>
</detail>
<detail>
<details></details>
<detail>
<Category B>
<details></details>
</detail>
</Category B>
```

The reason i want this is because i want the category as a Section in a tableview

Comment: [NSXmlparser](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=NSxmlparser&oq=NSxmlparser&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i61j0l3j69i60.589j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Have you parsed this XML???

Comment: @ArmaanStranger yes I use RaptureXML, i have the category and details already in a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to save in NSDictionary with the key is Category if its unique everytime. like

A={
    Details;
}
B={
    Details;
}

Like that. so that you can access all the category for Section Header.